# CS0106 compile error: readonly property and getter

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, language-design

It might look foolish but I wonder **why the following code produces me CS0106 compile-time error**:

`error CS0106: The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item`

The code:

```
class MyClass
{
private readonly int _value
{
  get
  {
    if (_value < 0)
      return -1 * _value;
    return _value;
  }
}
```

In my understanding I do nothing wrong inside `get` as I just read the value.
I agree that calculations for `readonly`'s property getter look awkward from the logical point of view.

P.S. Code inside `get` has no practical sense - it is just a "something that reads the `_value`"

**UPDATE**

In short initially I thought that it would be quite logic to make a readonly property by using `readonly` keyword.
I missed the main thing about `readonly` property that is available from Microsoft documentation:

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on **fields**.

Comment: the get only property is already like readonly thing. how ever the readonly keyword is for fields not properties

Comment: Even if you fix the `readonly` part, your property is now recursive. You need you declare  a separate field, too.

Comment: why do you want to put readonly on a Property?

Comment: Are you sure that you know what you are doing? It seems to me that you are trying to mash together a field and a property and they are two different things

Comment: vcjones is right. you will get stack overflow exception using this property

Comment: Thanks guys. This code is not for any real-world goal and what is within brackets for `get` has no sense - just some code that reads property's value.  I've played with the language in learning purposes. I was just curious - could I achieve readonly property with readonly keyword. Then I looked into the documentation more attentively. It states clearly: "The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on **fields**."

Comment: So it's just language design. I am not allowed to apply `readonly` keyword on anything other than fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No sarcasm...
You get a compile error because it's not part of the grammar for the language.

First, By nature of having only a `get`, then you're already making the property "readonly".

Second, you need to think of the property as syntactic sugar around two methods
`int getValue()` and `void setValue (int)`. Would it make sense to set the methods as "readonly"?

Third, setting the property as readonly wouldn't make sense since the property as a construct is not mapped to anything in memory. See the previous point about how it's basically a nice way of writing (up to) two methods.

Comment: Thanks Babak. Looks like I read documentation more carefully. It says "The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on *fields*." What I thought I should get is a property with no setter and I've expected that I can override default getter as I want until I am not writing to the `_value`. It looked logical to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Implementing only Get for a property is like already readonly. so if you want to achieve implementing the similar behavior, below will be the working code.

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly int _value = -5; // < some value> or<set it in the constructor>;
    private int ReadableValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Abs(_value); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhilash. I've played with the language in learning purposes. I was just curious - could I achieve readonly property with `readonly` keyword. Then I looked into the documentation more attentively. It states clearly: "The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on **fields**."

Comment: Or use `Math.Abs` which more clearly states your intention

Comment: @Default Thanks. Code inside get has no practical sense - it is just a "something that reads the _value"